# Get SQL Results Between Specific Weekdays and Times

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to get results in my query from a specific time period.  What I want to do is run a report on Saturday that will return results from between 7 AM on Monday of the current week to 5 PM on Friday of the current week (working hours).
I was able to do this:

```
BETWEEN DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 7, GETDATE()), 7) 
    AND DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 11, GETDATE()), 11)
```

However, that only gets the days.  How can I add the times?

Thanks in advance!

Update:
I wonder if you could help me one last time.  I added that date information to the query, but I am getting results about 5x what I would expect.  Let me post the whole code, so you can see what I'm doing:

```
DECLARE @inc INT, @out INT
SET @inc = (SELECT COUNT(SessionID) FROM altigen.dbo.CDRMAIN WHERE 
   DATEADD(ss, CAST((StartTime - 28800) AS INT), '1970-01-01') BETWEEN DATEADD(hh, 7, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 7, GETDATE()), 7)) AND DATEADD(hh, 17, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 7, GETDATE()), 7)) 
OR DATEADD(ss, CAST((StartTime - 28800) AS INT), '1970-01-01') BETWEEN DATEADD(hh, 7, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 8, GETDATE()), 8)) AND DATEADD(hh, 17, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 8, GETDATE()), 8))
OR DATEADD(ss, CAST((StartTime - 28800) AS INT), '1970-01-01') BETWEEN DATEADD(hh, 7, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 9, GETDATE()), 9)) AND DATEADD(hh, 17, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 9, GETDATE()), 9))
OR DATEADD(ss, CAST((StartTime - 28800) AS INT), '1970-01-01') BETWEEN DATEADD(hh, 7, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 10, GETDATE()), 10)) AND DATEADD(hh, 17, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 10, GETDATE()), 10))
OR DATEADD(ss, CAST((StartTime - 28800) AS INT), '1970-01-01') BETWEEN DATEADD(hh, 7, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 11, GETDATE()), 11)) AND DATEADD(hh, 17, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 11, GETDATE()), 11))
AND Direction = 1 AND VMDuration = 0 AND TargetWGNum IN ('200','201','210','211','212','240'))
SET @out = (SELECT COUNT(SessionID) FROM altigen.dbo.CDRMAIN WHERE 
   DATEADD(ss, CAST((StartTime - 28800) AS INT), '1970-01-01') BETWEEN DATEADD(hh, 7, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 7, GETDATE()), 7)) AND DATEADD(hh, 17, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 7, GETDATE()), 7)) 
OR DATEADD(ss, CAST((StartTime - 28800) AS INT), '1970-01-01') BETWEEN DATEADD(hh, 7, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 8, GETDATE()), 8)) AND DATEADD(hh, 17, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 8, GETDATE()), 8))
OR DATEADD(ss, CAST((StartTime - 28800) AS INT), '1970-01-01') BETWEEN DATEADD(hh, 7, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 9, GETDATE()), 9)) AND DATEADD(hh, 17, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 9, GETDATE()), 9))
OR DATEADD(ss, CAST((StartTime - 28800) AS INT), '1970-01-01') BETWEEN DATEADD(hh, 7, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 10, GETDATE()), 10)) AND DATEADD(hh, 17, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 10, GETDATE()), 10))
OR DATEADD(ss, CAST((StartTime - 28800) AS INT), '1970-01-01') BETWEEN DATEADD(hh, 7, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 11, GETDATE()), 11)) AND DATEADD(hh, 17, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 11, GETDATE()), 11))
AND Direction = 2 AND VMDuration = 0 AND TargetWGNum = 0 AND LEN(TargetNum) > 3)
SELECT @inc + @out AS TotalCalls
```

Basically, this is querying a call database to get the total number of incoming and outgoing calls between working hours, Mon-Fri.

- Target = 1/2 means incoming/outgoing, respectively
- TargetWGNum indicates the workgroup for the call, and should be within the list for incoming, or 0 for outgoing
- VMDuration = 0 means no voicemail was left
- The length of the target number means it wasn't to a three-digit extension (outgoing)
- The StartTime is store in epoch time, so I'm casting it as an integer before calculating.

Maybe there's a simpler, better way to do it, or just something I'm overlooking?  For this week, I'm expecting a few hundred calls, and I'm getting nearly 2,000 as the result for that query.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add hours:

```
BETWEEN DATEADD(hh, 7, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 7, GETDATE()), 7))
    AND DATEADD(hh, 17, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 11, GETDATE()), 11))
```

If you need to get results within working hours for each day you need to set the time ranges separately:

```
myDate BETWEEN DATEADD(hh, 7, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 7, GETDATE()), 7)) 
   AND DATEADD(hh, 17, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 7, GETDATE()), 7)) OR 
myDate BETWEEN DATEADD(hh, 7, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 8, GETDATE()), 8)) 
   AND DATEADD(hh, 17, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 8, GETDATE()), 8)) OR 
myDate BETWEEN DATEADD(hh, 7, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 9, GETDATE()), 9)) 
   AND DATEADD(hh, 17, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 8, GETDATE()), 8)) etc.
```

Update: if you have other conditions that follows the date/time condition in your WHERE clause do not forget to enclose the conditions with `OR` operator into brackets:

```
WHERE
(myDate BETWEEN DATEADD(hh, 7, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 7, GETDATE()), 7)) 
   AND DATEADD(hh, 17, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 7, GETDATE()), 7)) OR 
 myDate BETWEEN DATEADD(hh, 7, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 8, GETDATE()), 8)) 
   AND DATEADD(hh, 17, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 8, GETDATE()), 8)) OR 
 myDate BETWEEN DATEADD(hh, 7, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 9, GETDATE()), 9)) 
   AND DATEADD(hh, 17, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 8, GETDATE()), 8)) etc.
) AND Direction = 1 AND VMDuration = 0 AND ... etc.
```

Read about SQL Server operator precedence [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx) for more information

Comment: BTW, if you need to get values between working hours of each day, you need to use the conditions separately: `BETWEEN DATEADD(hh, 7, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 7, GETDATE()), 7)) AND DATEADD(hh, 17, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 7, GETDATE()), 7)) OR BETWEEN DATEADD(hh, 7, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 8, GETDATE()), 8)) AND DATEADD(hh, 17, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 8, GETDATE()), 8)) OR BETWEEN DATEADD(hh, 7, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 9, GETDATE()), 9)) AND DATEADD(hh, 17, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 8, GETDATE()), 8)) etc.`

Comment: Thank you very much!  Very useful information that I wouldn't have considered if you hadn't pointed it out.  You have been extremely helpful.  Kudos!

Comment: Any ideas regarding my update?  I'm a bit unsure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Read about SQL Server operator precedence http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx Basically, you need to include your conditions with `OR` operator in brackets

Comment: Thank you for the details and the informative link.